# Zend framework 2 upload files

Tags: php, zend-framework2, photo-upload

I want to upload photo in my application.

**ProductController.php**

```
    // ...
public function addAction()
     {

        $categories = $this->getCategoryTable()->fetchAll();
        $category_options = array();
           foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $category_options[$category->id] = $category->name;
            }
         $form = new ProductForm($category_options);
         $form->get('submit')->setValue('Pridať inzerát');

         $request = $this->getRequest();

         if ($request->isPost()) {

            $post = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
            );
             $form->setData($post);
             $product = new Product();
             $form->setInputFilter($product->getInputFilter());

             if ($form->isValid()) 
             {
                 $data = $form->getData();
                 echo var_dump($data);
                 $product->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                 $this->getProductTable()->saveProduct($product);
                 //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('product');
             }
         }
         return array(
            'form' => $form,
            );
     }
```

**ProductForm.php**

```
    class ProductForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($category_options)
    {

        parent::__construct('product');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Hidden',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options'=> array(
                'label' => 'Názov inzerátu:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'description',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Popis inzererátu:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Kategória inzerátu:',
                'value_options' => $category_options
                ),
            ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'phone',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Telefónne číslo:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Email:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'price',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Cena:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'location',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Mesto:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'shipping',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Odosiela do:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'top',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' =>'Topovať inzerát?',
                'value_options' => array(
                    'nie' => 'Nie',
                    'ano' => 'Áno'
                    ),
                ),
            ));

        $this->addPhotos();
        $this->addInputFilter();

        $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'submit',
             'type' => 'Submit',
             'attributes' => array(
                 'value' => 'Choď',
                 'id' => 'submitbutton',
                 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
             ),
         ));
    }

    public function addPhotos()
    {
        // File Input
        $file = new Element\File('image-file');
        $file->setLabel('Foto pre inzerát')
             ->setAttribute('id', 'image-file')
             ->setAttribute('name', 'image-file')
             ->setAttribute('multiple', true);
        $this->add($file);
    }

    public function addInputFilter()
     {
    $inputFilter = new InputFilter\InputFilter();

        // File Input
        $fileInput = new InputFilter\FileInput('image-file');
        $fileInput->setRequired(true);

        $fileInput->getValidatorChain()
            ->attachByName('filesize',      array('max' => 204800))
            ->attachByName('filemimetype',  array('mimeType' => 'image/jpeg, image/x-png'))
            ->attachByName('fileimagesize', array('maxWidth' => 100, 'maxHeight' => 100));

        $fileInput->getFilterChain()->attachByName(
            'filerenameupload',
            array(
                'target'    => './public/img/product.jpeg',
                'randomize' => true,
            )
        );
        $inputFilter->add($fileInput);

        $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
    }}
```

Its multiUpload form but if i want to upload photo form just insert the "product" and no photo. I use var_dump() to echo my array and its no change to my path. Next i want to write file path to database. All helps is welcome. Thanks.